# @import geolocator: Module 'geolocator' not found

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I created a Flutter project on the MacBook using Android Studio. The App works correctly on the Android phone and also on the iPhone connected to the Mac but when trying to generate the upload file for Apple it presents the error referenced in the GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m file

```
//// Generated file. Do not edit.//
#import "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"
#if __has_include (<geolocator / GeolocatorPlugin.h>)
#import <geolocator / GeolocatorPlugin.h>
#else
@import geolocator;
#endif
#if __has_include (<google_maps_flutter / FLTGoogleMapsPlugin.h>)
#import <google_maps_flutter / FLTGoogleMapsPlugin.h>
#else
@import google_maps_flutter;
#endif
```

Error: @import geolocator: Module 'geolocator' not found

I noticed that if you remove the part of the code that contains this call, the error will pass and be displayed on the next import, implying that everyone will have errors.

Could anyone help?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is should be in English

Comment: Changed friend, sorry

Comment: im not sure about flutter, im an ios native developer. but it seems like the dependency is not being linked/embedded with the application proprely. Might be worth checking this part to ensure geolocator is being packaged with your app properly. It would work on the simulator in this case but not on device

Comment: It is working on the simulator and also on the device.
I generated for my Iphone Xr (through Xcode) and it is working correctly, including geolocation. Only when I try to generate the file for sending to Apple does the error occur.
I hope someone can help.

Comment: is that fixed or found any work around for this issue? none of flutter clean/get/create didn't work
even I purged the entire IOS folder and created it again but didn't work. plz if someone could fix provide me the detail

Answer (score 5):

I was also getting an error just like this while archiving the build.

> module 'geolocator_apple' not found

After a lot of searching, I found out it was due to the different iOS Deployment Target in `Podfile` and in Xcode's Project Runner.

I made both same, it worked happily after.

Here are screenshots of both now after correction.

##### ios version in my Podfile

[image: ios version in my Podfile]

##### ios version in Project Runner

[image: ios version in Project Runner]

Comment: You are a legend! I had the same issue and this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons, the module related pod was not installed.
You may want to go to the project `ìos` folder and type (from the terminal):  `pod install`.
This should install the missing files and you should be able to build and run your project without any issue.